# How to get information in a json in a script by regex?

Tags: python, regex

I have a JSON and I want to get some information in it.
Use beautifulsoup and regex.

```
<script charset="gbk">
    var pageConfig = {
        compatible: true,
        product: {
            modules: [
                'address',
                'prom',
                'colorsize',
                'buytype',
                'baitiao',
                'summary',
                'o2o',
                'buybtn',
                'track',
                'suits',
                'crumb',
                'fittings',
                'detail',
                'contact',
                'popbox',
                'preview',
                'info',
                'imcenter',
                'jdservice',
                'commitments',
                'gift',
                'popupCar'
            ],
                    skuid: 11157027932,                                  
                    cat: [670,671,672],
                    commentVersion:'888',        
                    twoColumn: false,                
                    isFeeType: true,        
                    isCloseLoop:true,                                
                    isBookMvd4Baby: false,       
                    addComments:true,
                    mainSkuId:'10122299306',        
                    foot: '//dx.3.cn/footer?type=common_config2',
                    shangjiazizhi: false        }
    };
                            try {
                    function is_sort_black_list() {
          var jump_sort_list = {"6881":3,"1195":3,"10011":3,"6980":3,"12360":3};
          if(jump_sort_list['670'] == 1 || jump_sort_list['671']==2 || jump_sort_list['672']==3) {
            return false;
          }
          return false;
        }


</script>
```

I want to get like "cat" and "VenderID" in this JSON， how can I get these by regex?
I need the information [670,671,672] and skuid:11157027932

Comment: do you have any code that you have tried to solve this?

Comment: Welcome to SO. This is not a code-writing service. You need to show some effort and ask a specific question about a specific problem showing what you have already come up with.

Comment: the code I tried below.

Answer (score 0):

```
skuid: (\d+)
```

would get the value of skuid in the first capture group, see the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/eJfoZc/2)

```
cat: ([\[\d,\]]+),
```

would get the value of cat in the first capture group, see the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/eJfoZc/1)

Comment: sorry ,can you show me you use which function ? I use _a = re.search(r"cat:([\[\d,\]]+),",jsonstr)  this but return none

Answer (score 0):

I use BS4 get the soup of this script,

```
        for ss in thissoup.find_all('script')[0:1]:
        print ss
```

ss is the script.

```
        m = re.search(r"(?s)var\s+pageConfig\s*=\s*(\{.*?\});", ss)
        print m.group(1)
```

than I want to use this ,but error happened. 
I want to get a obj that I can get info like cat = Obj["cat"]